# How can I generate random files with size 1mb each from 1-500 using linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, dd

How can I generate random files with size 1mb each from 1-500 using linux shell script.

I wanted to create 100 random files in 500 directory locations but I am not able to create random files.
1 file with 500 directory is working with below command in shell script:

```
for i in {001..500}; 
do 
  for j in {001..001}; 
   do dd if=/dev/urandom 
       of=/home/h2h/pickup/AGENT_CH_${j}/AG_${j}_File${i}.csv bs=1M count=1;
   done
done
```

---

My directory locations as in format :

```
/home/h2h/pickup/AGENT_CH_001/
/home/h2h/pickup/AGENT_CH_002/
```

It' working fine to create 1 file each with 500 directories.
Now I am trying to generate 10 files for any random 100 directories.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: `for j in {001..001};` doesn't go too far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to have 100 random files in each 500 directories.

If so, try this:

```
for d in {001..500}; do 
  for f in {001..100}; do 
    dir="/home/h2h/pickup/AGENT_CH_${d}"
    [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir -p "$dir"
    dd if=/dev/urandom of="${dir}/AG_${d}_File${f}.csv" bs=1M count=1
  done
done
```

Comment: You must change this:
mkdir -p "{dir}" --> mkdir -p "${dir}"